# How to declare a global variable and access it in all the other modules in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, module, global-variables, react-component

Being new to ReactJS, I wanted help with the global variable declaration and usage. The scenario is that I have different modules and I want to access a variable which is available in all the modules, irrespective of their relations. To be precise, I have an admin panel and a user dashboard which have no common parent. But, I wish to set a value of a variable in admin panel and use that value in user dashboard and other modules. I tried looking out for solutions but couldn't get a feasible solution. It would be a great help if the solution is explained using an example.

Comment: are you using Webpack for bundling ?

Comment: @JonasLochmann I wanted information if there is a concept like Global Variable declaration and accessing it through modules in ReactJS, just like JavaScript

Comment: @SubhanshuPandey yes, I'm using Webpack for bundling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about your exact use-case and what is most suitable for you, but there are several patterns more suitable to concepts of react, that provide an ability to use shared variable in different components:

- Declare a variable in the top-level container-component and pass it down through props to desired children.
- Use state managers (Redux, Mobx etc.) and access state (any kind of data) from any component.
- [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Making a parent for both the components and passing states between them solved my problem. For my use case, I defined the Admin Home Page Component (where the state was set) and User Login Component (where I had to access the state) into a common Parent Component and defined this Parent Component into App (where all the other components were defined). This solved my issue of accessing the state of the component and providing it to another component which had no common relationship.